# symfony2 doctrine cache_driver type APC

Tags: php, apache, symfony, doctrine, apc

I am having a server that run both production and testing.

php apc is enabled.

For production, parameters.yml - doctrine **cache_driver** type is APC.

For testing,  parameters.yml - there is no **cache_driver** type for the doctrine.

But, when I load the testing site, I got this

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot inherit
>   previously-inherited or override constant ROLE_DEFAULT from interface
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface

And there is no issue on the production site.

Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.